# i want to store id and name of one table from sqlite database to spinner. i need to store two column inforamtion in one spinner

Tags: android, sqlite

here i get only single value and save it in `spinner` but i want to retrieve two column value in one spinner

```
public List<String> getAllLabels1(){
    List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();


    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT WeatherPrediction.CropID as CropID, Crop.Name as Name FROM Crop INNER JOIN " +
                  "WeatherPrediction ON Crop.CropID = WeatherPrediction.CropID order by Name";

     SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
     Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            labels.add(cursor.getString(0));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // closing connection
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    // returning lables
    return labels;
}
```

Comment: Create a model java class with two variables. pass the class object to spinner and custom adapter of spinner..

Comment: just use `SimpleCursorAdapter`, thats all